# Is there some way to bind a click to a ng-container?

Tags: angular, ng-container

I've got a component made of a `ng-container`, I would like to bind a click on it. `(click)` doesn't do the job.

Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: You can't because ng-container doesn't get rendered in the html template. So, since the code wont be transpiled in the actual DOM, that element will not exists at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `@HostListener('click', ['$event'])` in the code does the job.

Asking the question made me think of it.

Answer (score 1):

the `ng-container` will not render as an element so there is no way you can rise the click event

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickHandler]'
})
export class ClickHandlerDirective {

   @HostListener('click', ['$event']) log(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

this will not rise any click event

```
<ng-container appClickHandler>
  <div>
    ng container  with click 
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

but you can add the click handler to an element inside the ng-container

```
<ng-container >
  <div appClickHandler>
    ng container  with click 
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3a4hky)

> **ng-container**
>   The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Here's the conditional paragraph again, this time using .

```
<p>
  I turned the corner
  <ng-container *ngIf="hero">
    and saw {{hero.name}}. I waved
  </ng-container>
  and continued on my way.
</p>
```

[ng-continer doc](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer)

Comment: That won't do the trick for me, I want to build a custom button component that uses the classes specified when the component is used `<my comp class="my-classes`></my-comp>

Comment: I still don't get what are you try to do can you update your question put a code and explain more about what are you try to do so we can help 

Comment: Isn't this: `<ng-container >
  <div appClickHandler>
    ng container  with click 
  </div>
</ng-container>` the same as: `<ng-container >
  <div (click)="method()">
    ng container  with click 
  </div>
</ng-container>

Answer (score 1):

Tested in NG v11, you can do something like this where you wish to insert the custom template:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of listData; index as i">
        <ng-container
            [ngTemplateOutlet]="customTemplate"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
                $implicit: item,
                idx: i,
                onclick: this.clickHandlerMethodInComponent.bind(this)
            }"
        ></ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then define the custom template like this:

```html
<ng-template #customTemplate
    let-item
    let-index="idx"
    let-onclick="onclick">

    <a (click)="onclick(item)">
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </a>
</ng-template>
```

The key is to use the **ngTemplateOutletContext** attribute and the binding of the click handler to the component.

Comment: The call to `bind(this)` in `this.clickHandlerMethodInComponent.bind(this)` is what did it for me. Interestingly, removing the first `this` works for me in angular v13 in 2022: `clickHandlerMethodInComponent.bind(this)`. Ty